# Unable to send an action to another Jason agent

Tags: artificial-intelligence, agent, artificial-life

I am using Jason language to communicate between two agents. But I am unable to use send action, it gives an error.

These are my two agents,

Agent1:

```
// Agent Agent1 in project factorial3.mas2j

/* Initial goals */
!start.

/* Plans */

+!start : true
<- .print("starting..");
    !query_factorial(2).

+!query_factorial(X) : true <-
.send(agent2,tell,giveme(X)).

/*+fact(X,Y) : true <-
.print("factorial ", X, " is ", Y, " thank you expert").*/
```

Agent2:

```
// Agent agent2 in project IdEx.mas2j

/* Initial beliefs and rules */

/* Initial goals */

!begin.

/* Plans */

+!begin : true
    <- .print("expert starting.......");
        !giveme(X).

+!giveme(X):true
    <- !fact(X,Y);
    .print("Factorial of ", X, " is ", Y).
    //.send(agent1,achive,fact(X,Y)).
    
+!fact(X,1) : X == 0.

+!fact(X,Y) : X > 0
<- !fact(X-1,Y1);
    Y = Y1 * X.
```

So, I am getting this error when I am trying to call send action in agent1 and agent2 gives an receive error.

```
[agent2] *** Error adding var into renamed vars. var=X, value=(_229-1).
java.lang.ClassCastException: jason.asSyntax.ArithExpr cannot be cast to jason.asSyntax.VarTerm
    at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.prepareBodyForEvent(TransitionSystem.java:877)
    at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.applyExecInt(TransitionSystem.java:728)
    at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.applySemanticRule(TransitionSystem.java:222)
    at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.reasoningCycle(TransitionSystem.java:1429)
    at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.run(CentralisedAgArch.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I updated with the error code.

Comment: I don't believe that this is all that is to it, but in Agent2's .send, achieve is missing an 'e'. And then, you try to send fact(X,Y). Try giving this another name and receiving it in Agent1.

Comment: @JanithaMadushan: Have you found a solution? If so, to serve others, would you consider posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ask for an agent to perform a plan (in case of agent1 when you say `+!query_factorial(X)...)` it should be an achieve message. Uncommenting the "plan" `+fact(X,Y) : true <- .print("factorial ", X, " is ", Y, " thank you expert")` you should use the operator `!` at the begining to make it a plan. So, if I undertood the general idea of your test project, it can be rewritten as follows:

Agent1 code:

```
!start.

+!start : true
<- .print("starting..");
    !query_factorial(2).

+!query_factorial(X) : true <-
    .send(agent2,achieve,giveme(X)).
```

Agent2 code:

```
+!giveme(X):true
    <- !fact(X,Y);
    .print("Factorial of ", X, " is ", Y).

+!fact(X,1) : X == 0.

+!fact(X,Y) : X > 0
    <- !fact(X-1,Y1);
    Y = Y1 * X.
```

You can see, I am not using the "begin plan" of your original code since the Agent1 is doing the job, making Agent2 work when asked.